# How to change label using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the content of an HTML label, but I do not have the capability to edit the HTML. Therefore, I am trying to change the text using CSS. Is there any selector to identify the label below, and if there is, how could I make the text show the word "Organization" instead of "Company"? Thank you.

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="company" style="">Company</label>
<div class="controls">
<input id="settings-company" class="settings-company input-xlarge" type="text" data-config="required" value="My Organization" name="company">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use jquery or javascript for DOM modification. can't change through css

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hide the text with `font-size:0;` and add a pseudo element.

```
label { font-size: 0; }
label:before { content: "Organization"; font-size: 14px; }
```

Comment: Drip, thanks for this...If i have multiple labels on the page, is there any way to uniquely identify this one? The unique tag on the html element is "for=company"

Comment: You can target it like this `label[for="company"]{  }`

Comment: This will hide any label, and show "Organization" in all of them. +1 for @drip comment but not for the answer (+1 for the answer if you ammend it explaining that point). -1 for both because it don't change the content as asked for, just change what "most users can see". Any crawler will find "company", screen readers will read "company"... in general

Comment: (sorry, send it before finishing)  I think it's not a good solution. I gave no upvote or downvote, but content should be in html and style in css, mixing "information" and "look" is not a nice thing. (Still wondering something better that maybe don't exists)

Comment: @miguel-svq the question is "How to change label using CSS?", not "How properly to target a label". ;) Because we can start an argument why the CSS is on one line, why the pseudo element uses `:` instead of `::`, why I'm using `px` etc... ( which are outside the scope of the question ) And of course that this it's not a good solution, but for pages that you can't change the HTML structure or add JS, it works. ( for example the Shopify checkout page, that allows to make only CSS changes and nothing else )